# A scenario about the calendar in Java in which explicitly setting a date leads to some diffrent result

Tags: java

Let's look at the following code snippet in Java.

```
package demo;

import java.util.Calendar;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2011, 11, 11);   //Setting a date to itself.

        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " 

        + cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) + " 

       " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    }
}
```

---

In the above simple code, I'm temporarily (and **explicitly**) setting the current date to itself which is 2011-11-11 using the method `cal.set(2011, 11, 11);`. Accordingly, I get the output **2011 51 345**, the current year **2011**, the week of the year **51** and the day of the year **345**.

---

When I leave a comment on that line which is `cal.set(2011, 11, 11);`, I get the result, **2011 46 315** the current year, the current week of the year and the current day of the year respectively which is different from the earlier result.

[Here, I'm not setting any date. The statement `cal.set(2011, 11, 11);` in the above code is commented out and the system is automatically retrieving the current date which is 2011-11-11].

---

In both the cases, the same date is used which is **2011-11-11** still the result obtained is different in both of the cases. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The month value is 0-based. If you meant November, use:

```
cal.set(2011, 10, 11);
```

See the [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) javadocs.

Answer (score 4):

The month is zero indexed in Java.  You're setting it to December 11th when you choose month 11.